# Calling an expression to my table using pdf make

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created a table using pdf make and I want each cell (Region, Group, etc) to be displayed in my view.

Here is the table in the js exported using Pdf Header:

```
            exporterPdfHeader: {
                margin: [30, 5, 30, 15],
                table: {

                widths: [ '*', '*', '*' /*, '*'*/ ],

                body: [
                  [ 'Region: ', 'Group: ', 'MC: ' ],
                  [ 'District #: ', 'Route #: ', 'Week Ending Date: ' ]

                ]
              }  

            },
```

Below is an example of my view

```
<div class="selection-header well well-sm">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <label>Region:</label>
        <span>{{searchFilter.region.description}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <label>Group:</label>
        <span>{{searchFilter.group.description}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <label>MC:</label>
        <span>{{searchFilter.marketCenter.description}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <label>District #:</label>
        <span>{{searchFilter.district.description}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <label>Route #:</label>
        <span>{{searchFilter.route.description}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <label>Week Ending Date:</label>
        <span>{{searchFilter.endWeek.description}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the cell that contains Region to call this argument and be exported using pdf make, how can i do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you are confusing "mustache argument" with "angular view". Mustache is a logic-less templating framework. This also doesn't _much_ resemble angularJS...

Comment: @DanielShillcock Thank you for clarifying.  Would you be able to help me with my issue or do you need more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first created a scope test outside the gridoptions.  Then set the scope to the getData function.

```
$scope.test = ''

$scope.getData = function(){
...
$scope.test = $scope.searchFilter.region.description;
}
```

This is the expression declared in the html

```
    {{searchFilter.region.description}}</span>
```

Finally I set the pdfheader within the broadcast

```
$scope.$on('net', function(event, filter) {

    $scope.gridOptions.exporterPdfHeader = {
        margin: [30, 5, 30, 15],
        table: {

            widths: [ '*', '*', '*' ],

            body: [
              [ 'Region: '+ $scope.region, 'Group: ', 'MC: '],
              [ 'District #: ', 'Route #: ', 'Week Ending Date: ']

            ]
          }  

    };  

    $scope.export();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow some basic angularJS tutorials to get to grips with rendering two-way data binding data. Below is an Angular example of what you wish to achieve. Take a look at the below example, and modify the `userInfo` to become your `docDefinition`. You are likely going to need nested `ng-repeat` however this is easily researchable.

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module['ExampleApp,[]);
app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.userInfo= [
                     {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
                     {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
                     {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}
                          ];
})
```

**View**

```
<body ng-app='ExampleCtrl'>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
         </tr>
         <tr ng-repeat="info in userInfo">
            <td>{{info.name}}</td>
            <td>{{info.country}}</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
</body>
```

**Result**

```
<body ng-app='ExampleCtrl'>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Jani</td>
         <td>Norway</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Hege</td>
         <td>Sweden</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Kai</td>
         <td>Denmark</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: I have updated the code on what I want to do. Within gridOptions I am exporting this table as the header using pdf make.  Would this example still apply?

Comment: The data I am trying to call is created by selecting an item in the search box, so would I have to put all that data in its own array?